# CsvReader DateTimeKind UTC

Tags: c#, datetime, streamreader, utc, serialization

The CsvReader serializer is transforming the string "2017-01-09T00:01:47.6145940Z" into local time, But I would like to keep the records in UTC.

Without passing a Map, is there a way to define the DateTimeStyle?

Here is the conversion code:

```
using (var reader = new StreamReader(lakeStream))
using (var csv = new CsvReader(reader, new CsvConfiguration()
{
    HasHeaderRecord = hasHeaderRecord,
    Delimiter = delimiter,
    IgnoreBlankLines = true,
    IsHeaderCaseSensitive = false,  

}))
{
    rows = csv.GetRecords<T>().ToList();
}
```

I tried CultureInfo but couldn't make it to work

Comment: Where exactly is the `CsvReader` class coming from? As far as I know there's nothing like that in the standard framework.

Comment: You could deserialize it to a `String` and parse it yourself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By default, parsing DateTime will always return local time. You either have an option to use this code, (`DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind` will preserve the DateTime kind from the input string), assuming `value` is a string containing your date:

```
DateTime parsedDate;
DateTime.TryParseExact(value, "o", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.RoundtripKind, out parsedDate);
```

Or use `ToUniversalTime()` on the parsed object as the other answer suggests.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can't override the code that converts the CSV date to a `DateTime` value, you could correct it after conversion, assuming your row type (`class`) doesn't have an immutable property for the value (i.e. you can re-set the value).

```
rows = csv.GetRecords<Row>().ToList();

foreach(Row row in rows) {

    row.SomeDateValue = row.SomeDateValue.ToUniversalTime();
}
```

Comment: Agreed, but since OP wants UTC, I believe that call should be `ToUniversalTime()` instead of `ToLocalTime()`.